# Is local compactness preserved by continuous closed onto functions?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, compactness

I've just shown for a homework problem that if $f$ is an open continuous function from $X$ onto a $T_2$-space $Y$, and $X$ is locally compact, then $Y$ is locally compact. I wonder, does this hold for closed continuous functions too? Intuitively, I want to say no, but I'm not sure if I can find a counter example. Am I correct? How can I prove / disprove it?

Comment: "Locally connected" in the first sentence should say "locally compact", I assume?